# What types of bonds that you can only redeem but not sell in secondary markets?

Tags: united-states, bonds

There are some types of bonds that you can only redeem (e.g. I bonds), but not sell. In addition to I bonds, what other types of bonds that you can only redeem but not sell in secondary markets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Treasury Direct](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/savings-bonds/forms/):

> Savings bonds, like EE, HH, and I bonds, cannot be "marketed." They cannot be bought and sold after you own them.
>
> Other Treasury securities (without a letter designation like E, EE, H, HH, or I) can be sold after you buy them. And you buy them only at an auction. Thus, they are "marketable."